# JSON Array - Help needed with displaying data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

```
{
"entries": [
    {
        "id": 23931763,
        "url": "http://www.dailymile.com/entries/23931763",
        "at": "2013-07-15T21:05:39Z",
        "message": "I ran 3 miles and walked 2 miles today.",
        "comments": [],
        "likes": [],
        "user": {
            "username": "DeanaLaughli",
            "display_name": "Deana O.",
            "photo_url": "http://s3.dmimg.com/pictures/users/361413/1329826045_avatar.jpg",
            "url": "http://www.dailymile.com/people/DeanaLaughli"
        },
        "workout": {
            "activity_type": "Fitness",
            "distance": {
                "value": 5,
                "units": "miles"
            },
            "felt": "great"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 23931680,
        "url": "http://www.dailymile.com/entries/23931680",
        "at": "2013-07-15T21:01:03Z",
        "message": "More strength training",
        "comments": [],
        "likes": [],
        "location": {
            "name": "MA"
        },
        "user": {
            "username": "Ecm2571",
            "display_name": "Eileen",
            "photo_url": "http://s3.dmimg.com/pictures/users/323833/1368556483_avatar.jpg",
            "url": "http://www.dailymile.com/people/Ecm2571"
        },
        "workout": {
            "activity_type": "Weights",
            "title": "Upper and lower body "
        }
    }
]
}
```

Here is an example of a JSON array that I am getting via JSONP request from a URL. I am trying to display:

- photo_url
- username
- message
- location.name
- workout.activity_type
- workout.duration
- workout.distance.value
- workout.distance.units

However, as you can see in the array sometimes this information isn't given and when this happens the code stops loading more entries. I need a way to display a blank space when there is no data to load. Here is my code, thanks for any help.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

$(function() {

var entries = [];
var workout.activity
var dmJSON = "http://api.dailymile.com/entries.json?callback=?";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
$.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
  var tblRow =      "<tr>" + 
            "<td><img src=" + f.user.photo_url + "></td>" +
            "<td>" + f.user.username + "</td>" + 
            "<td>" + f.message + "</td>" + 
            //"<td>" + f.location.name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + f.workout.activity_type + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + f.workout.duration + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + f.workout.distance.value + f.workout.distance.units + "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
   $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
});

});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="1">
<thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    <th>Exercise Type</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
    <th>Distance</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll get errors when `f.workout.distance` is undefined (because it is in the 2nd response). *Read the error console to first determine what is wrong*. Establish guards or sentinels or use a "path evaluator".

Comment: A simple guard with the ternary operator: `f.workout.distance ? f.workout.distance.value + f.workout.distance.units : ""` - but for anything non-trivial this is better written taking the larger context into account (e.g. don't show last td?).

Comment: Is there a way to initialise/set the value to blank, so when the data isn't in the array it just shows as blank?

Comment: Arrays are not an issue here (`{..}` delineates a JSON/JS *object*, not an array). And yes, you could do that too. For instance, at the top of the each/generation function: `f.workout.distance ||= { value: '', units: 'Not applicable' }`; however, consider if this is appropriate here or makes future refactoring harder. I would actually suggest to change the HTML-string generation to an incremental builder (i.e. build each TD one at a time) or template with basic conditional support. This would allow using an "if" around the offending region to customize the result better.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will take your advice into consideration and shake up the code a bit.

Comment: Questions should not be removed after they have been answered, someone may encounter the same problem and benefit from the post.

Comment: @Maggy as mentioned above, it is completely improper to edit your question out like that. It remains here for others to find later to help them. Even worse, though; you must never edit answers like you tried to do below.

Answer (score 2):

First all run it in chrome and open the web tools.
Once your "reach" error you will see the error in the console log.

Your problem is that you have undefined values that you try to read.
You can solve it by checking each object before you try to read any value form it or to use function which return default value whenever teh value is missing.

Here is a full working code for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        /**
         * Extract the property formthe object.
         * If teh property not found it will return empty string
         */
        function getProperty(object, property) {

            if (!property) {
                return '';
            }

            var
            // Break the property to its nested properties
                    properties = property && property.split('.'),
            // the current object that we want to extract the property from
                    current = object,
                    index;

            // Loop over the properties and process them
            for (index = 0; index < properties.length; index++) {
                property = properties[index];
                // Check to see that there is a property with the given name
                if (current.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    current = current[property];
                } else {
                    return '... N/A ...';
                }
            }

            // If we got so far it means the the 'current' contain the needed value
            return current;
        }

        $(function () {

            var entries = [],
                    dmJSON = "http://api.dailymile.com/entries.json?callback=?";

            $.getJSON(dmJSON, function (data) {
                $.each(data.entries, function (i, f) {
                    var tblRow = "<tr>" +
                            "<td><img src=" + getProperty(f, 'user.photo_url') + "></td>" +
                            "<td>" + getProperty(f, 'user.username') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + getProperty(f, 'message') + "</td>" +
                        //"<td>" + f.location.name + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + getProperty(f, 'workout.activity_type') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + getProperty(f, 'workout.duration') + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + getProperty(f, 'workout.distance.value') + getProperty(f, 'workout.distance.units') + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";

                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
        <table id="entrydata" border="1">
            <thead>
            <th></th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Exercise Type</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Distance</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, was not sure exactly how to get to this conclusion so this is very helpful for me.